# Discrete Mathematics Induction Proof

Tags: combinatorics

You are walking around a circle with an equal number of zeroes and ones on its boundary. Show with induction that there will always be a point you can choose so that if you walk from that point in a clockwise direction, you will always have seen at least as many zeroes as you have ones.

---

So, suppose the P(k) case holds. In the next case, where an extra one and an extra zero is added, I can see that the old path will suffice so long as you will encounter the extra zero before the extra one. But what about in the other situation, if you encounter the extra one before the extra zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding on an extra one and an extra zero to an arbitrary circle with $k$ ones and $k$ zeros, its better to think of it as removing a one and a zero from an arbitrary circle with $k+1$ ones and $k+1$ zeros, and reducing the problem to the inductive hypothesis: because it is not immediately clear that adding a one and a zero to all such circles encompasses all circles with $k+1$ of each digit.

That being said, here is how I would approach the problem. The base case is clear, start so that you first cross the only one on the circle.

Suppose we know that for every circle with $k$ ones and $k$ zeros, we can perform the described task. Consider an arbitrary circle with $k+1$ ones and $k+1$ zeros. We look for a one which precedes a zero, which must exist, and remove each of these from the circle. If we can traverse this circle with $k$ ones and $k$ zeros in the manner described, then we can also do it for the circle with more ones and zeros, simply because when we reach the segment where the previously removed one and zero were, the net change in the difference between number of ones and number of zeros seen is nonnegative along this segment (because the one precedes the zero).

This shows that the inductive hypothesis $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$, where $P(k)$ is the statement that it can be done with $k$ ones and $k$ zeros.

Edit: An approach which is more geared towards actually finding the starting position could be found like this: we do a 'test run' around the circle, starting at any position. At all points around the circle, we keep track of the value: "number of ones seen so far minus number of zeros seen so far", which could sometimes be negative. We should then start when this quantity is minimal, because if we start from there, and keep track of the same quantity as before, by definition it cannot go below zero (otherwise the minimum would've been reached elsewhere).

Comment: Yes! I understand now, thank you very much